# Error when trying to create a model in PowerDesigner through Java

Tags: java, com, powerdesigner

The actual code

```
package OOM.src.createOOM;

import org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COM;
import com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.PdCommon.*;
import com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.PdOOM.*;

/**
 * @author Xiao Wang
 *
 * This Java sample program shows how to use PowerDesigner Java proxies and 
 * OLE automation to create a PowerDesigner OOM model and display the contains of the OOM model.
 */
public class CreateOOM {

   /** PowerDesigner application object */
   private Application pdApp;
   
   private int nbClasses;
   
   /** 
    * Program entry point 
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("shhs");
          // Create an instance of this class
          CreateOOM createOOM1 = new CreateOOM();
          // Create an OOM and display the result
          createOOM1.CreateAndDisplayOOM();
       }
   /**
    *  Create an OOM and display the result 
    */
   public void CreateAndDisplayOOM() {
      int hr = COM.OleInitialize(0);
      try {
         // Get PowerDesigner application instance and start PowerDesigner if necessary
         pdApp = Application.getInstance();
         if (pdApp != null)
         {
            // Create an OOM
            Model newModel;
            newModel = createOOM();
         
            // Show the information of the current OOM
            showOOMInfo();
                 
            // Release PowerDesigner application.  
            // This may close PowerDesigner if PowerDesigner was started by this program.
            // pdApp.Release();
         }
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Cannot create PowerDesigner application object.  Please verify that PowerDesigner is installed.");
      }
      finally {
         if (hr == COM.S_OK)
            COM.OleUninitialize();
      }
   }
      
   /**
    *  Create an OOM for Java
    */
   public Model createOOM() {
      try {
         // Create an OOM model, use Java as the language, create a default class diagram
         // Convert the return object to PdOOM.Model proxy object
         Model newModel = new Model(pdApp.CreateModel(PdOOM_Classes.cls_Model, "|Language=Java|Diagram=ClassDiagram"));
         // set name and code
         newModel.SetName("Customer Management");
         newModel.SetCode("CustomerManagement");
         //System.out.println("reach");
         // Create a customer class.  
         // Use the fully qualified name here to avoid conflict with Java
         com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.PdOOM.Class newClass1 =
            new com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.PdOOM.Class(newModel.GetClasses().CreateNew());
         newClass1.SetName("Customer");
         newClass1.SetCode("Customer");
         newClass1.SetComment("Customer class");

         Attribute newAttribute;
         // Create an id attribute
         newAttribute = new Attribute(newClass1.GetAttributes().CreateNew());
         newAttribute.SetName("Id");
         newAttribute.SetCode("id");
         // id is the primary identifier (primary key)
         newAttribute.SetPrimaryIdentifier(true);
         // set the Java data type
         newAttribute.SetDataType("int");

         // Create a name attribute
         newAttribute = new Attribute(newClass1.GetAttributes().CreateNew());
         newAttribute.SetName("Name");
         newAttribute.SetCode("name");
         // set the Java data type
         newAttribute.SetDataType("java.lang.String");

         // Create a phone attribute
         newAttribute = new Attribute(newClass1.GetAttributes().CreateNew());
         newAttribute.SetName("Phone");
         newAttribute.SetCode("phone");
         // set the Java data type
         newAttribute.SetDataType("java.lang.String");

         // Create an email attribute
         newAttribute = new Attribute(newClass1.GetAttributes().CreateNew());
         newAttribute.SetName("Email");
         newAttribute.SetCode("email");
         // set the Java data type
         newAttribute.SetDataType("java.lang.String");

         // Create an SalesOrder class.  
         // Use the fully qualified name here to avoid conflict with Java
         com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.PdOOM.Class newClass2 =
            new com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.PdOOM.Class(newModel.GetClasses().CreateNew());
         newClass2.SetName("SalesOrder");
         newClass2.SetCode("SalesOrder");
         newClass2.SetComment("Sales order class");

         // Create an orderId attribute
         newAttribute = new Attribute(newClass2.GetAttributes().CreateNew());
         newAttribute.SetName("Order id");
         newAttribute.SetCode("orderId");
         // id is the primary identifier (primary key)
         newAttribute.SetPrimaryIdentifier(true);
         // set the Java data type
         newAttribute.SetDataType("int");

         // Create an orderDate attribute
         newAttribute = new Attribute(newClass2.GetAttributes().CreateNew());
         newAttribute.SetName("Order date");
         newAttribute.SetCode("orderDate");
         // set the Java data type
         newAttribute.SetDataType("java.util.Date");

         // Create an association
         Association association1 = new Association(newModel.GetAssociations().CreateNew());
         // Set linked classes
         association1.SetObject1(newClass1);
         association1.SetObject2(newClass2);
         // Set role A name and multiplicity
         association1.SetRoleAName("customer");
         association1.SetRoleAMultiplicity("1");
         // Set role B name and multiplicity
         association1.SetRoleBName("orders");
         association1.SetRoleBMultiplicity("0..*");

         // Get the default class diagram
         ClassDiagram newDiagram = new ClassDiagram(newModel.GetDefaultDiagram());

         // show the symbol in the default diagram if it is a class diagram
         newDiagram.AttachObject(newClass1);
         newDiagram.AttachObject(newClass2);
         newDiagram.AttachLinkObject(association1);
        
         return newModel;
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return null;
      }
   }
   
   /**
    *  Display information about the currnt OOM
    */
   public void showOOMInfo() {
      try {
         // Get the current OOM model
         if (!pdApp.GetActiveModel().isNull())
         {
            if (pdApp.GetActiveModel().IsKindOf(PdOOM_Classes.cls_Model))
            {
               // Convert the active model to an OOM model proxy object
               Model aModel = new Model(pdApp.GetActiveModel());

               // Initialize the number of classes
               nbClasses = 0;
                              
               // Display a message in PowerDesigner outut window
               pdApp.Output("Display the list of classes in the system output window.");
               
               // Show classes and packages defined under the model
               // Convert model proxy object to package proxy object
               showPackageInfo(new com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.PdOOM.Package(aModel));
               
               System.out.println("There are " + nbClasses + " class(es) in this model.");
               
            }
            else
            {
               System.out.println("The current model is not an OOM model.");
            }
         }
         else
         {
            System.out.println("There is no active model opened in PowerDesigner.");
         }
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   /**
    *  Display information about an OOM package
    */
   public void showPackageInfo(com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.PdOOM.Package aPackage) {
      if (!aPackage.isNull() && !aPackage.IsShortcut())
      {
         // Display the number of classes and packages in the system output window
         System.out.println("The " + aPackage.GetObjectType() + " '" + aPackage.GetCode() + "' contains " + aPackage.GetClasses().GetCount() + " class(es), " + aPackage.GetPackages().GetCount() + " package(s).");

         // Use the fully qualified name here to avoid conflict with Java
         com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.PdOOM.Class aClass;
         for (int n = 0; n < aPackage.GetClasses().GetCount(); n++)
         {
            nbClasses++;
            if (nbClasses < 100)
            {
               // display class info
               aClass = new com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.PdOOM.Class(aPackage.GetClasses().Item(n));
               showClassInfo(aClass);
            }
            else
            {
               if (nbClasses == 100)                
                  System.out.println("...");
               break;
            }
         }

         // display classes of subpackages         
         com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.PdOOM.Package subPackage;
         for (int nPackage = 0; nPackage < aPackage.GetPackages().GetCount(); nPackage++)
         {
            subPackage = new com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.PdOOM.Package(aPackage.GetPackages().Item(nPackage));
            showPackageInfo(subPackage);
         }
      }
   }
   
   /**
    *  Display information about a class
    */
   public void showClassInfo(com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.PdOOM.Class aClass) {
      try {
         if (!aClass.isNull() && !aClass.IsShortcut())
         {
            System.out.println("Class No." + nbClasses + ": " + aClass.GetCode() + ", " + aClass.GetAttributes().GetCount() + " attribute(s), " + aClass.GetOperations().GetCount() + " operation(s)");
         }
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

The issue im getting is--

org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Action can not be performed. result = -2137456383 (com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.com.COMException:  COM Failure [HRESULT: 0x80990101])
at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OLE.error(OLE.java:345)
at com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.com.COMException.raiseOnFail(COMException.java:83)
at com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.com.IDispatchEx.raisingInvoke(IDispatchEx.java:231)
at com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.PdCommon.IApplication.CreateModel(IApplication.java:84)
at OOM.src.createOOM.CreateOOM.createOOM(CreateOOM.java:68)
at OOM.src.createOOM.CreateOOM.CreateAndDisplayOOM(CreateOOM.java:42)
at OOM.src.createOOM.CreateOOM.main(CreateOOM.java:28)
Caused by: com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.com.COMException:  COM Failure [HRESULT: 0x80990101]
at com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.com.COMException.raiseOnFail(COMException.java:88)
... 5 more
There is no active model opened in PowerDesigner.

how can I resolve this?

Comment: Doesn't the tool's documentation tell you? From the stacktrace it seems you'd need to open a model first before trying to perform the action you've tried. If that action is to open a model there might be a bug in the tool so maybe ask SAP support to get more knowledgable help.

Comment: Im trying to run this after opening a model, but still the error.

Comment: You've provided pretty minimal set of information here. Does this happen always, or just with one model? Did it work earlier? What did you do when it stopped working?

Comment: Hi James,  This is the first time i'm trying to establish a connection through java to the PowerDesigner. My requirement is that to access the repository using Java. The code i'm trying to run is from the Sample codes provided in the OLE Automation folder of the Power Designer- 'C:\Program Files\SAP\PowerDesigner 16\Ole Automation\Java Samples/'. There is a sample program in the Java Samples folder to create a model in PD which im trying to run.